# Pass GeoJSON from .NET to Javascript

Tags: postgis, javascript, openlayers-2, query, .net

My .NET/OpenLayers/GeoServer/PostGres-PostGIS application allows users to create custom queries to get data from my PostGIS tables.

The queries are called in .NET (not javascript) using a web method  using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT "tract_name", ST_AsGeoJSON("geom") FROM a_postgis_table;
```

The query works fine when I run it in the PostGres SQL window.

How can I pass the  PostGIS results, including the GeoJSON column, back to javascript/openlayers from the .NET web method so that OpenLayers can render the vector layer in the map? There has to something really simple I am missing here. Seems like this should be an extremely common thing that people need to do.

Comment: What .NET web framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three parts to getting your solution.

1. Creating a GeoJSON FeatureArray
2. Returing the FeatureArray from .NET
3. Consuming that on the client

1) GeoJSON FeatureArray. 
Easiest way (IMHO) is to write a Postgresql query to do that. There's a guide [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/267-Creating-GeoJSON-Feature-Collections-with-JSON-and-PostGIS-functions.html) on how to do that, but, assuming tract_name is unique your query could be something like this:

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc)
 FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
 FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type
    , ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geom)::json As geometry
    , row_to_json(lp) As properties
   FROM a_postgis_table As lg 
         INNER JOIN (SELECT tract_name FROM a_postgis_table) As lp 
       ON lg.tract_name = lp.tract_name  ) As f )  As fc;
```

2) .NET service
There are lots of ways to do this, but I have done this in the past using WCF / svc if I've got my terminology correct. Here's a little VB sketch:

```
    <OperationContract()> _
            <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, 
BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate:="GetTracts")> _

    Public Function GetTracts() As Stream

            ' Code to get your Postgresql Feature set into a string
    dim json as String = "" ' The sql output


    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json))

            Return ms

        End Function
```

3) Get it into OpenLayers ( works for v 2)

I assume you have created an empty vector layer in OpenLayers called "myTracts". You can do something like this:

```
 var request = OpenLayers.Request.POST({
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: '{}',
        headers: {
            //          contentType: "text/plain"
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        callback: onGeoJsonLoadSuccess
    });
 function onGeoJsonLoadSuccess(data) {

// Assuming your server data are in lon/lat
 var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                'internalProjection': map.baseLayer.projection,
                'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            });

// You might want to empty the features first...

myTracts.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(data);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with .NET, but if you are able to modify the DOM from the .NET method you could write the data to a hidden div on which a change listener is registered. eg using jQuery:

```
$.("#data").bind('contentchanged', function() {
    //do something with data
)};
```

When the event fires, the function gets triggered and you can handle the data. Another way would be to write the data to a file and load it using AJAX. For both methods you need to modify the DOM, though, as you need to let JavaScript now what to load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JavascriptSerializer** to convert your .Net list to JSON or GeoJson.

**GeoJsonList** refers to list in data

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(GeoJsonList);
```

Comment: No need to do that - ASP.NET does that for you if you do it properly. http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/